# knockoutJs, when to use ko.computed

Tags: knockout.js

I am so confused by ko.computed.  not sure when to use it.  I have 2 statements.  Can you please explain to me whats the difference and when to use them ?

```
self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
});


self.fullName = function() {
    return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For displaying a fullName, either of those options will result in the same thing. What makes computed a better difference to a function is that you can assign a read and write sub function. That way you can change the observables with the computed value instead of a seperate function.

In the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rynan/E4wAC/), you can see if you change firstName or lastName, both will change. But if you change the computed First or Last name it will change that one and the function as well.

Also, see the [computed documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) for more examples.

Comment: thank you so much for showing your code on fiddle.  Now I understand the difference between those two.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that when you use ko.computed, if you bind to fullName, fullName will automagically be updated whenever either firstName or lastName changes. Without ko.computed, you'd have to do that work yourself.

Comment: please correct me if i m wrong, if I change the value of the first name, the web page will automatically update the full name.  If I dont use ko.computed, I need to call fullname to update the value.

Comment: There is no difference in displaying

Comment: i think if you dont use computed you have to use subscribe http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html